# How to work with an asynchronous database

Tags: javascript, html

I have:

```
for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    dbo.transaction(
        function(myTrans) {
            myTrans.executeSql(
                'UPDATE myTable SET myField=0 WHERE myID=?'
                ,[i]
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Because the function is a callback, it is being called with i=2.
Q: How do I call it with i=0 and i=1?

Note: I *think* that's what is happening.  I think I've stated the problem correctly (that it's caused because the callback executes after the loop is finished).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably right about what the bug is. The solution to this is to wrap an anonymous function around the inside of the loop, which holds a new and unchanging `i` variable for the enclosed code to see.

```
for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    (function(i) {
        dbo.transaction(
            function(myTrans) {
                myTrans.executeSql(
                    'UPDATE myTable SET myField=0 WHERE myID=?'
                    ,[i]
                );
            }
        );
    })(i);
}
```

ECMAScript Harmony (the proposal for the next version of JavaScript) includes [a new keyword, `let`](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=proposals%3ablock_expressions&rev=1192996588#let_statement), which will make a bit cleaner. It will work like this:

```
for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    let (i = i) {
        dbo.transaction(
            function(myTrans) {
                myTrans.executeSql(
                    'UPDATE myTable SET myField=0 WHERE myID=?'
                    ,[i]
                );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

It might even be possible to just replace `var i` with `let i`, but as far as I know consensus hasn't yet been reached on this point.

Comment: "let (i = i)"  Oh yeah, that's much cleaner. </sarcasm>

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn: I've edited the post to mention that it may be possible to just replace `var` with `let` and make no other changes. I think we can agree that that would be cleaner. :P I do consider ES:Harmony example to be cleaner than than the current JavaScript one, but I concede that this isn't the best example of where it could be used.

Comment: My sarcasm was reserved for ES:Harmony, not for your explanation and code samples.  In fact your code is very clean.  I just have a hard time with JavaScript in general.

Answer (score 3):

Use anonymous function to capture the variable:

```
for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    (function(i){
        dbo.transaction(
            function(myTrans) {
                myTrans.executeSql(
                    'UPDATE myTable SET myField=0 WHERE myID=?'
                    ,[i]
                )
            }
        )
    }(i));
}
```